# Set Range.Text without breaking Fields?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I need to remove some text from a Word document footer which also contains fields (e.g. for the page number). Simple, right?

However, when I update the text in the range it breaks the fields that it contains. For example, the page number field becomes just a number (rather than a field which stays up to date).

Is there a way to change the text in a range without affecting the fields it contains?

Here is my current code:

```
string wordToRemove = "foo";            

foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
{
    foreach (HeaderFooter footer in section.Footers)
    {
        if (footer.Range.Text.Contains(wordToRemove))
            footer.Range.Text = footer.Range.Text.Replace(wordToRemove, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me just make sure I'm understanding correctly.  Are you working from an existing template, or are you looking through a document for the words?  (inserting/evaluating)?

Comment: @confusedandamused The code is looking for the text to replace in the footers of the active document. The scenario is that the user will be working on their document and will use my addin to change the footers in the active document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Simple, right?

Indeed - as soon as you know about `Find` *property* (?!) of the `Range` object:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Returns a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Find object that contains the criteria
//     for a find operation.
Find Find { get; }
```

which in turn provides a handy `Execute` method with a lot of options, and more importantly, has the desired non destructive behavior:

```
string wordToRemove = "foo";

foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
{
    foreach (HeaderFooter footer in section.Footers)
    {
        footer.Range.Find.Execute(FindText: wordToRemove, ReplaceWith: "", Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works perfectly and those options are going to be incredibly useful for other things. I never guessed that what I wanted would be under "Find". I'm sure there must be a good reason that they put it there...maybe! :-) I'll aware the bounty as soon as it lets me.